# Russian visa refusal stamp

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, russia

Russian Visa application refused because the old visa did not cover an older refusal stamp?

I applied myself for a russian visa 5 months ago and got refused on the spot because my documents were wrong. A month later I applied through a visa center and I got my visa accepted at the embassy.

Now I want to apply again (through a visa center) but when the visa center took the documents to the embassy, the embassy said that it seems like i tried to apply again and got refused, they think that since the Visa did not cover the refusal stamp since 5 months ago, which lead them to think that I'm already refused.

What do you think about this situation?

Comment: Did you go to the embassy directly or to a visa application centre?

Comment: the first time i went alone and got refused, then i went to visa center and got accepted, now with visa center again

Comment: Okay so the visa center called, and asked me to provide them with the original voucher that i gave to the embassy when I applied my self and with the date and time of my interview back then.

Comment: Do you still have that voucher? If so, follow their instructions. That's it really, do whatever they sak you to, and if there's something you can't do, explain it

Comment: Did you get the accepted visa?Or did you get accepted **in visa center**?

Comment: If you got the visa, why can't you show it to the embassy? You should reword your question, right now it's very confusing